# RMI and JBOSS naming exception

Tags: jboss, rmi

I have an application running on JBoss 6. JBoss runs on a local machine whose IP is
192.168.0.105 and which is behind a router. The router IP is, for example, 83.200.200.200. I run JBoss with this command:

```
run.sh -b 192.168.0.105 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=83.200.200.200
```

But when I invoke client from remote application using address 83.200.200.200 (which has forwarding) I get an exception:

> Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [sslsocket://192.168.0.105:3843/]]

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Try run -b 0.0.0.0 and see what happens. Are you able to ping 83.200.200.200 from client box?

Comment: Does java.rmi.server.hostname really work with JBoss Remoting?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it. On my machine where I run JBoss, in /etc/hosts I have added a line:

192.168.0.105       mydomain.com

and run JBoss with -b mydomain.com

and on machine from I connect remotely I have added a line in /etc/hosts

83.200.200.200      mydomain.com

and everything works great. Thanks for your answers